# Pass a Bundle to startActivityForResult to achieve Scene Transitions

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, transition

I am playing around with Lollipop `sceneTransitionAnimations`.

To get it to work you need to implement `getWindow().setExitTransition()` + `getWindow().setReenterTransition()` in the calling activity's `onCreate`, 
and `getWindow().setEnterTransition()` + `getWindow().setReenterTransition()` in the called activity's `onCreate`.

Then, when you call `startActivity` you have to pass a `Bundle` to that function that you obtain by calling `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity()).toBundle()`.

This works fine. However I need to start an activity using `startActivityForResult`. This function only takes an `Intent` and a `requestCode`, but no `Bundle`. Putting the bundle into the intent using `putExtras` did not work.

How do I get these nice Lollipop transitions to work when I want to use `startActivityForResult`?

**EDIT as I was asked for code:**

I am inside a Fragment, I have a list of items. When an item is clicked I start another activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, otherActivity.class);
Bunde bundle = null; 
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    bundle = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity()).toBundle();
```

now here come the two distinctions. This one works:

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

The Fragment does not offer this function, so I have to use its parent activity's - hence the `getActivity()`.

This one does **not** work:

```
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: **"Putting the bundle into the intent using putExtras did not work."** : What does that mean? SHow your code.

Comment: **"However I need to start an activity using startActivityForResult. This function only takes an Intent and a requestCode, but no Bundle."** : It seems to me you may have missed the method `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)`

Comment: Huh, now that's embarassing. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Squonk I have come to realize that the method I am trying to use, `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)` actually exists.

I had done the mistake of trying to start that from a Fragment, where it is not implemented - same as `startActivity(Intent intent, Bundle bundle)` - so you need to call `getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)` .

Comment: But won't it mean that the onActivityResult be called on the activity instead of the fragment?