# android startActivityForResult not including Bundle

Tags: android, fragment, android-support-library

I am developing an app. And min SDK is 14. And now i am going to open new Activity from Fragment, when user clicks button on the fragment.

//code that open new activity

```
newFavoriteFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CategoriesActivity.class);
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putInt(BundleConstants.OPERATION_TYPE, OperationTypes.ADD_FAVORITE);
            mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
            startActivityForResult(mIntent, ActivityStartRequestCode.ADD_FAVORITE);
        }
    });
```

//activity onCreate method, which trying to open

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
//here, when i am going to get it, i see that bundle argument is null
```

I tried to make it over the activity, but it says me that: Call requires API level 16. Because i use API 14 as minumum.

```
 getActivity().startActivityForResult(mIntent, ActivityStartRequestCode.ADD_FAVORITE, mBundle);
```

Please provide working solution. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive the data from started activity use `getIntent()` in `onCreate` method.

That is,

```
 Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CategoriesActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra(BundleConstants.OPERATION_TYPE, OperationTypes.ADD_FAVORITE);
            startActivityForResult(mIntent, ActivityStartRequestCode.ADD_FAVORITE);
```

to receive, use in `onCreate()`:

```
Intent received = getIntent();
int var = received.getInt(....);
```

Anyway, if you namely want the bundle, use something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16073980/1979882 or this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31021165/1979882